# getting 256 color support in non-x11 terminal

Tags: raspbian

Is it even possible? I'm using raspbian. It works when I use lxterminal but I don't want to have to use the X window system.

Comment: Could you elaborate the question? As far as I understand, lxterminal is an X application. It sends it's output to X and X displays it on the screen. You cannot run it without X. But, you may run it with X without LMDE - is this what you want to do??

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things that will do this, I think.  The only one I've tried is [fbterm](http://code.google.com/p/fbterm/), which is available in raspbian.  It uses the framebuffer and lets you use installed X fonts, etc (read the man page, and look at the config file `~/.fbtermrc`).

However, as noted on the home page, it doesn't use the same ANSI sequences for 256 colors as xterm, so console apps which exploit that (how many are there, lol?  apparently emacs, I dunno what else...) won't be in 256 colors.

In theory, you can also set a background image, however, I think you will need `fbv` (not `fbi`) which does not come with raspbian.

In any case, it is easy enough to install and try.

Comment: According the the fbterm site it includes a terminfo database for fbterm that supports 256 colors so any programs that use terminfo (or ncurses) should handle 256 colors.